# Polymer 1.0: Is there any way to use 'layout' as an attribute instead of as a CSS class or using Attribute serialization in the class attribute?

Tags: javascript, html, polymer, web-component, polymer-1.0

I have built my application in polymer 0.5.

Now I have updated it to polymer 1.0.

For responsive layout I have used a layout attribute using custom logic of layout attributes in the Polymer 0.5.

See the code below:

```
<template is="auto-binding">
<core-media-query query="max-width: 767px" queryMatches="{{smallScreen}}"></core-media-query>
<section layout vertical?="{{smallScreen}}" horizontal?="{{!smallScreen}}">
    <section flex four?="{{!smallScreen}}" auto?="{{smallScreen}}">
        <paper-input-decorator label="First name" floatingLabel>
            <input type="text" is="paper-input" id="fname" name="fname">
        </paper-input-decorator>
    </section>
    <section flex four?="{{!smallScreen}}" auto?="{{smallScreen}}">
        <paper-input-decorator label="Last name" floatingLabel>
            <input type="text" is="paper-input" id="lname" name="lname">
        </paper-input-decorator>
    </section>
</section>
</template>
```

Now in polymer 1.0 introduce one element "iron-layout-flex" and all indications are that now instead of attributes we must work with the classes ".layout", ".horizontal", ".vertical"? It is very confusing that how should I adjust as per my logic of the layout attribute.

So, my question is that Is there any way to use 'layout' as an attribute instead of as a CSS class or using Attribute serialization in the class attribute?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you could theoretically translate attributes to the new layout css properties. Something like this (untested, so no guarantees this will actually work)

```
<style is="custom-style">
  html /deep/ [layout][vertical] {
    @apply(--layout-vertical);
  }

  html /deep/ [layout][horizontal] {
    @apply(--layout-horizontal);
  }

  html /deep/ [flex][four] {
    @apply(--layout-flex-4);
  }

  html /deep/ [flex][auto] {
    @apply(--layout-flex-auto);
  }
</style>
```

Comment: It would be the answer. But, it will require more work in building a custom CSS. I have already thought that, but if there are any updates in layout classes in next updates of polymer, then I will have to manually add into my custom CSS file. That's not a proper way to use polymer.

Comment: I think, There may be an alternate way that doesn't force me to make new custom CSS and only from HTML logic I can handle this situation.

Comment: have you found a solution to this issue? I mean, what is the best approach to handle layout on polymer? if so, please comment this post. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

As of Polymer 1.2 it's now possible to use `compound binding` see [Polymer Blog](https://blog.polymer-project.org/releases/2015/11/02/release-1.2.0/).

Meaning, you should now be able to do the following:

```
<div class="someOtherClass [[addClassIf('horizontal', smallScreen)]] [[addClassIf('vertical', !smallScreen)]]" >
</div>

..
smallScreen: {
   type: Boolean,
   value: false,
}
..

addClassIf: function(classToAdd, shouldAdd)
{
   if(shouldAdd)
      return classToAdd;
}
```

There's probably some other (better) way to do this now that `compound binding`  works. But this shows the concept on how it can be done.